# VBA find and replace word Text Box

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an Excel program.

Which is manipulating a word document and find/replace text. My code looks like this

```
    Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document

Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wApp.Visible = False
Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(myFile)
                        
With wDoc.Content.Find
    .Text = "<Customer Name>"
    .Replacement.Text = "Customer Name"
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                
    .Text = "<Billing Address>"
    .Replacement.Text = "Billing Address"
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

Which works perfectly.

However the word document has some words within a text box which I want to find and replace on, but I can't get it to work (the above code only searches the main body of the word document and not the text boxes)

I tried

```
    wDoc.Shapes.Range(Array("Text Box 14")).Select
With wDoc.Selection.Find
    .Text = "<Profile Code>"
    .Replacement.Text = "Profile Code"
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

but that didn't work.
I got an Object doesn't support this property or method error message

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the text box is named "Text Box 14" the following should work for you (it works for me in O365)

```
   With wDoc.Shapes("Text Box 14").TextFrame.TextRange.Find
      .Text = "<Profile Code>"
      .Replacement.Text = "Profile Code"
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .MatchWholeWord = True
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   End With
```